# In Pandas, how to create a unique ID based on the common interrelation of other columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with two IDs columns. I need to set a unique common interrelated ID with te following condition: if either ID1 or ID2 has some of them in common, they must have the same common_ID (ID_3).

The dataframe looks like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID_1': ['111', '111', '222', '333', '333', '444', '555', '666', '666', '777'],
               'ID_2': ['AAA', 'BBB', 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'EEE', 'DDD', 'FFF', 'CCC']})
```

The desired output should be as follow:

| ID_1 | ID_2 | ID_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | AAA | 1 |
| 111 | BBB | 1 |
| 222 | AAA | 1 |
| 333 | BBB | 1 |
| 333 | CCC | 1 |
| 444 | DDD | 2 |
| 555 | EEE | 3 |
| 666 | DDD | 2 |
| 666 | FFF | 2 |
| 777 | CCC | 1 |

```
df_output = pd.DataFrame({'ID_1': ['111', '111', '222', '333', '333', '444', '555', '666', '666', '777'],
                      'ID_2': ['AAA', 'BBB', 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'EEE', 'DDD', 'FFF', 'CCC'],
                      'ID_3': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '3', '2', '2', '1']})
```

to clarify the conditions

In 1st and 2nd row ID_1 the same, so they must have the same ID_3.

The 3rd row has the same ID_2 as 1st row, so its ID_3 must be the same as 1st row = 1.

The 4th row has the same ID_2 as 2nd row, that's why it must be set the same ID_3 as 2nd = 1.

The 5th row has the same ID_1 as 4th, so ID_3 = 1.

The 6th row has a unique combination of ID_1 and ID_2 at this moment, so it's marked as ID_3 = 2.

Than 7th row = 3.

But 8th has the same ID_2 as 6th, so ID_3 = 2.

and so on

Comment: kindly paste output as code or a table, not pics

Comment: here you are ))

Comment: Can you clarify your condition? Why have some rows ID_3 = 1 and others 2. Where is the "common" aspect?

Comment: Your criteria is not clear. Why does the first and second row has the same ID_3?

Comment: in 1st and 2nd row ID_1 the same, so the must have the same ID_3
the 3rd row has the same ID_2 as 1st row, so its ID_3 must be the same as 1st row

Comment: but 3rd and 4th row are not same, why ID3 is still 1?

Comment: the 4th row has the same ID_2 as 2nd row, that's why it must be set the same ID_3 as 2nd

Comment: the 6th row has unique combination of ID_1 and ID_2 at this moment, so it's marked as ID_3 = 2

Comment: So what if first cell of ID_2 was `BBB`. What would be the ID_3 then?

Comment: If first row were 111/BBB its  ID_3 still = 1, but 3rd row in this case would have ID_3=2, because 222/AAA would be the unique combination

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think we can use [`networkx`](https://pypi.org/project/networkx/) to solve this:

```
import networkx as nx

G=nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(df[['ID_1','ID_2']].to_numpy().tolist())
cc = list(nx.connected_components(G))
L=[dict.fromkeys(b,a) for a, b in enumerate(cc,1)]
d={k: v for d in L for k, v in d.items()}
out = df.assign(ID_3=df['ID_2'].map(d))
```

---

```
print(out)

  ID_1 ID_2  ID_3
0  111  AAA     1
1  111  BBB     1
2  222  AAA     1
3  333  BBB     1
4  333  CCC     1
5  444  DDD     2
6  555  EEE     3
7  666  DDD     2
8  666  FFF     2
9  777  CCC     1
```

To see connected components:

```
print(cc)
[{'111', '777', '222', 'AAA', '333', 'BBB', 'CCC'}, 
 {'DDD', 'FFF', '666', '444'}, {'555', 'EEE'}]
```

Comment: thanks a lot!
I have been straggling for a week to solve.

Comment: Wow never expected networkx to be included in the solution for the pandas problem. Learnt something new.

Comment: @Pygirl networkx has a `nx.from_pandas_edgelist` method too for adding edges. :)